# Approximation for $\int dx\, f(x) / (x-x_0) \exp (-g(x)^2 / (x-x_0)^2)$

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation, gaussian-integral

Is there an approximation that can be made for

$$\int dx\, \frac{f(x)}{x-x_0} \exp \left(-
\frac{g(x)^2}{(x-x_0)^2} \right)$$,

where $g(x_0) = 0$? I know that a thin Gaussian can be approximated as a Dirac delta function, but this seems to be slightly different. Is there a systematic expansion that can be made?

Comment: What are the bounds on the integral?

Comment: We can take it to be $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Okay (you should edit that into your question!). What is known about $f$ and $g$? Can we say anything about the nature of the singularity in $f(x)/(x-x_0)$ at $x=x_0$? Similarly for $g$: Only knowing that $g(x_0)=0$ isn't enough to determine the behavior of the exponent near $x_0$